# OpenGL ES 1.1 on iOS: Stack size for the GL_PROJECTION matrix mode

Tags: ios, matrix, opengl-es

this question is related to the old OpenGL|ES 1.1 implementations on iOS devices (tested only with iOS7). We have some existing code that still relies on the old OpenGL fixed function pipeline where I tried to fix a bug.

After some investigations i figured out that the bug happens because of a GL_STACK_OVERFLOW error for the glPushMatrix(GL_PROJECTION) call. Logging out the MAX and the CURRENT stack depth returned for the GL_PROJECTION matrix a surprising result. OpenGL reports me a max depth size of 2 for the GL_PROJECTION matrix stack?!?!?! In contrast, the GL_MODELVIEW matrix stack has a depth size of 16.

Is there any reason for this? Does there exist some documentation why the stack size for the projection matrix is only 2. Its a bit less from my point of view, isn't it?

I was looking for some docs on Apple side but without any success. Could someone point me to a documentation where the stack sizes are documented?

I am just curious about that fact. Does the OpenGL implementation on Apple side had always such a stack size restriction.

Any infos about that topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here for more info on 1.1 http://www.khronos.org/opengles/1_X/

And here the limits http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/ The minimum required is 16 for GL_MODELVIEW and 2 for GL_PROJECTION and GL_TEXTURE

Comment: Thanks, was so confused not checking the details in the specs.